# Why XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer fails when other user is offline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I am using XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer and XMPPIncomingFileTransfer to transfer file data. When both users are online, i am able to send file data. But when any one user go to offline then it fails to send file data and following delegate is called.

```
    - (void)xmppOutgoingFileTransfer:(XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer *)sender
            didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

And the error is

```
  Error Domain=XMPPOutgoingFileTransferErrorDomain Code=503 "<service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>}
```

How can i send file data to offline user.
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XMPP, file transfer is negotiated between parties. There is several XMPP specifications for file transfer, but to get a better idea of how it works, you can read one of them, like [XEP-0234 Jingle File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html). This is basically Session Initiation, that is the negotiation of a transfer of data out-of-band directly between the peer or via a proxy. This is designed for live transfer (much like a phone call for example, except this is another type of data).

There is new specification that support upload a file to a shared space over HTTP and link sharing to download it: [XEP-0363 HTTP File Upload](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363.html). However, you need to make sure your library and your server supports it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mickaël.